# Attach user data to AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have userdata in my instance. I am able to crete AMI but user data is not attached to AMI. Whenever I have to create new instance using AMI, I have to add user data again. How can I attach user data to AMI ?

I have added user data for each new instance.

Comment: User Data is an attribute of an Amazon EC2 instance, not an AMI. There is software called `cloud-init` on the AMI that will look at the User Data and determine whether it is a script. If so, it will run the script.

Comment: If the user data remains the same for all instances, you can just create one instance with that user data and create an ami and for all other instances, use that ami.

Comment: @Riz that's not correct. If the user-data has to do something like start up a service after boot, that sort of thing will not persist on the AMI.

Comment: It sounds like you should create a script on the instance that runs on boot (without using user-data), and then create an AMI from that.

Comment: @MarkB, you are right. I got the idea that he needs to have some services already installed, like apache etc whenever he wants to create a new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a [launch template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/launch-templates.html) or [launch configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/launch-configurations.html) based on your ami.

Otherwise, you have to manually setup [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) on the instance before you make custom AMI from it to run your scrypt. UserData is just executed by cloud-init on the instance.